# ASP.NET cannot launch IIS Express

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I've tried others' solutions such as installing IIS 8.0 instead of IIS 10, deleting my IIS config or reinstalling Visual Studio 2015 to no avail.

The error appears to be happening when it's trying to deploy the application to the IIS web server, since the application indeed builds (the output says that build succeeded, but doesn't even bother trying to deploy it). Indeed, when I try to view it via CTRL+SHIFT+W it says that it cannot launch IIS Express.

This is what the debugger says:

```
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

When I try deselect "Enable Edit and Continue" in the Project Settings, it just says that it can't launch IIS Express rather than Unknown Error.

What could possibly be happening?

Comment: To my knowledge, "Edit and Continue" is not supported in ASP.NET projects.

Comment: @Dai, well, it's disabled; I disabled it as part of my troubleshooting. Right now, I'm just left with "Unable to Launch IIS Web Server".